# Sequelize HasMany BelongsToMany removes old reference

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having a problem that the old reference gets removed when I create a new instance. I will show my code and give an example, what am I doing wrong?

`var Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING
},
{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Users.hasMany(models.Interest,{ as: 'interests'});
    }
  }
}
);`

...

`var Interest = sequelize.define('Interest', {
    category: DataTypes.STRING,
    value: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Interest.belongsToMany(models.Users,  {through: 'UsersInterest'});
      }
    }
  });`

first I create an interest alone

`models.Interest.create({
      value: data.value,
      category: data.category
    }).then(function(newInterest) {
         //allgood
      });`

`
//data holds the information the instance needs

```
models.Users.create({
  name: data.name,
  email: data.email

}).then(function(newUser) {
    //data interest contains the interest to find and add
    for (var i = 0; i < data.interests.length; i++) {
      models.Interest.findOne({
        where: { value: data.interests[i].value, category: data.interests[i].category},
      }).then(function(interest) {
          newUser.addInterest(interest).then(function() {
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

`
When I create the first one its all good, look:

`{"user":{"id":1,"name":"Chelo","email":"chelo@intelli.com","interests":[{"value":"kitesurf","category":"sport"}]}}`

until now, all good, after I add the second one..

`{"user":{"id":1,"name":"Chelo","email":"chelo@intelli.com","interests":[]}}
{"user":{"id":2,"name":"CACA Cavazzoli",email":"chelo@intelli.com","interests":[{"value":"kitesurf","category":"sport"}]}}]}`

When I create a second instance with the same interest, then the interest from the first one is removed...

What am I doing wrong?

Please help!!!

Comment: If you're trying to do a many to many. You'll need to do this on the User model instead of a `hasMany`.

`Users.belongsToMany(models.Interest,  {through: 'UsersInterest'});`

Comment: @LT- thanks!! will try it, if it works, you can write it as an answer to earn Reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I was doing something wrong. Thanks @LT- for your comment.
I will give the correct code that I changed:

`var Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING
},
{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Users.belongsToMany(models.Interest,{ as: 'interests', through: 'UsersInterest'}); 
    }
  }
}
);`

Basically, I have added belongsToMany on both sides, on Users and on Interests.

Hope it helps.